# Active Reports: Group (multiple column report) details based on Column 1.

Tags: report, activereports, componentone

I would like to Group the details section of my report in this way.
Can anyone help me as I am new to Active Reports?
I could not find any posting related to this kind of Grouping. 
Another kind of grouping exists, but that is on top of each dataset.

One way is to manipulate the DataTable  that I am binding to the report. 
But I don't want to go that route.

I am sure that Active Reports should have an option for a grouping like this. 
I just cannot figure it out.

Can anyone guide me?

### **Current Data:**

`...............................................
Column1 (Membership)    Column2 (Person) 
...............................................

1                        Person1

...............................................

1                        Person2 
...............................................

1                        Person3 
...............................................

1                        Person4 
...............................................

2                        Person5 
...............................................

3                        Person6 
...............................................

4                        Person7 
...............................................

4                        Person8
...............................................

5                        Person9 
...............................................

5                        Person10 
...............................................

6                        Person11 
...............................................`

### **DESIRED Data**

`...............................................
Column1 (Membership)    Column2 (Person) 
...............................................

1                        Person1


                         Person2 

                         Person3 

                         Person4 
...............................................

2                        Person5 
...............................................

3                        Person6 
...............................................

4                        Person7 

                         Person8
...............................................

5                        Person9 

                         Person10 
...............................................

6                        Person11 
...............................................`

Answer (score 1):

The expected behavior can be achieved by explicitly setting the Visible property of the TextBox (displaying the field on the basis of which grouping has been done) to False when it has been printed once in the Detail Section.

In order to get the desired output, please follow the under-metioned steps :

1. Right-Click on the ReportDesigner and Insert Group Header/Footer
2. Select the Group Header and open it's Property Dialog
3. Set the DataField property to Column1. Select Ok
4. In the Detail Section, drag and drop two TextBox controls
5. Set the DataField property of

   TextBox1 : Column1

   TextBox2 : Person
6. In the Detail's Format event, toggle the visibility of the TextBox1, using the following script :

   Dim counter as integer

   Sub Detail_Format

   ```
   If counter < 1 then     

   TextBox2.Visible=True
   ```

   Else

   ```
   TextBox2.Visible=False
   ```

   End If

   ```
       counter=counter+1
   ```

   End Sub
7. Reset the value of the counter for every group in the following manner :

   Sub GroupHeader1_Format

   ```
   counter =0
   ```

   End Sub

Regards,
Mohita